Why do these 2 unconnected objects rotate together?
This is what happening
Can I get help with this rotate issue? When I rotate one of them, the other one rotates too even though they don't have any connection.

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

The objects are close together and you have Proportional Editing turned on:

Proportional editing affects many objects based on distance of the selected objects that are being transformed:

Hit  O  or toggle the button in the UI to disable it
